# Behaviour of async/await in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await

Given the following Node.js express route:

```
router.route('/user')

   .post(async function(req, res) {
       if(req.body.password === req.body.passwordConfirm) {
           try {
               var response = await userManager.addUser(req.body);
               res.status(201).send();
           } catch(err) {
               logger.error('POST /user failed with error: '+err);
               res.status(500).send({err:"something went wrong.."});
           }
       } else {
           res.status(400).send({err:'passwords do not match'});
       }
   })
```

and the corresponding function in userManager:

```
var userManager = function() {

    this.addUser = async function(userobject) {
        userobject.password_hash = await genHash(userobject.password_hash);
        var user = new User(userobject);
        return await user.save();
    };

};

module.exports = userManager;
```

Can I safely assume that if the code in the catch block **does not** run, there were **no errors**? Since the `userManager.addUser` and everything inside it return promises, which if rejected, should be caught by the catch block. 
Or did I miss something and should I still check the response for validity?

Comment: If you get something in your `response` variable it means there were no errors **yet**. But some still can be thrown by `res.status(201).send();` for example (it will be fine in your case, but let's assume you have more code in the `try` block).

Comment: To be clear: by "something" I mean anything, even `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: In this case Model.save() (mongoose) returns a promise so it would never be null or undefined. So in this case I would be ok as you said.

Comment: `null` or `undefined` are not errors, unless you `throw null` or `reject(null)` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely assume all errors *from `await userManager.addUser(req.body)`* are caught.

If the promise returned is rejected with value `x`, then the `await` keyword ensures it'll `throw x`.

But that doesn't ensure there are no errors outside that function call, like in your `catch`.

#### Best practice:

`post()` doesn't expect an `async` callback function, so it'll ignore your implicitly returned promise.

So when you pass it one, wrap `try`/`catch` around everything, since there's no-one to pass up to:

```
router.route('/user').post(async function(req, res) {
    try {
        if (req.body.password === req.body.passwordConfirm) {
            try {
                var response = await userManager.addUser(req.body);
                res.status(201).send();
            } catch (err) {
                logger.error('POST /user failed with error: '+err);
                res.status(500).send({err:"something went wrong.."});
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({err:'passwords do not match'});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('POST /user fatal error: '+err);
    }
})
```

This way all programming errors are caught and never end up silenced or as unhandled rejections.

Or better, if it's an option, write a `post` that expects an async function.

Comment: I am hesitant to accept this question because it got downvoted and I don't know why..

Comment: I don't know either.